# Understanding Hard Disk Sector Size

Tags: kernel, ntfs, hard-drive, sector

I'm currently developing a kernel mode driver that interacts with raw disk operations.

I wish to understand more about the concept of Sector Size.
Is a sector size a constant value per physical drive that was set when the HDD was manufactured ?

Or is it defined by the file system that is formatted on the Disk ? If so can they be 2 Sector Size ? One for the physical disk and one for the File System ?

I know for example that NTFS has in its BIOS Parameter Block a DWORD called "sector size", is this the NTFS FS sector size ? Or is it the Physical HDD sector size ?

Thanks a lot
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the sector size is established by the drive manufacture.

According to wikipedia:

> The standard sector size of 512 bytes for magnetic disks was established with the inception of the hard disk drive in 1956
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector

Hard drives have typically been shipped with 512 byte sectors. That was until January 2011, when hard drive manufactures unanimously switched to 4k sectors.

> As all hard drive manufacturers have agreed to transition to the
>   Advanced Format sector design by January 2011
>   http://www.seagate.com/tech-insights/advanced-format-4k-sector-hard-drives-master-ti/

Querying the device for its sector size is not reliable. It is not uncommon for drives report the wrong sector size.

> Unfortunately, some HDD manufacturers do not properly respond to the
>   device inquiry sizes. ... The problem is that some HDDs misrepresent
>   4KB sector disks as having a physical sector size of 512 bytes.
>   http://wiki.illumos.org/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=1147716

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/274376-32-change-sector-size-4096